wish to generate the quarto report for demographic data for each patient in a particular format
Please consider that you have the demographic data and we need to generate the patient profile for each subject. its easy to generate that report for each patient via quarto, however i have an issue with the format.
I want the format as below

you see the highlighted headers, that what the issue i have
I tried the below code
---
title: "Demographic Report of `r params$subject` "
format: html
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  message: false
params: 
  subject: '01-701-1015'
---


library(tidyCDISC)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
data <- tidyCDISC::adsl %>% rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  select(usubjid, trt01p, age, sex, race, heightbl, weightbl, rfstdtc, rfendtc) %>% 
  filter(usubjid == params$subject)


#| echo: false

kable(data %>% select(-usubjid))




A custom template will be required, I guess. You may have a look on article layout pieces: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html and grid customization: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/page-layout.html
